# Sorting the dates and assigning a rank - python

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose I have data like,

```
user    date
1   3/18/2016
1   1/11/2015
1   1/11/2015
1   5/8/2015
1   7/8/2015
2   3/17/2016
2   2/10/2015
2   9/8/2015
2   1/1/2016
2   1/1/2016
```

I want to sort the rows based on the dates for each user and then create a new column, which would assign 1-5 rank for each date.

The following are by tryings,

`df.groupby(['user']).sort_values(['date'])` for sorting the dates for each user. But I want to create a new column which would rank after sorting.

My ideal output would be,

```
user    date    rank
1   1/11/2015   1
1   1/11/2015   1
1   5/8/2015    2
1   7/8/2015    3
1   3/18/2016   4
2   2/10/2015   1
2   9/8/2015    2
2   1/1/2016    3
2   1/1/2016    3
2   3/17/2016   4
```

Can anybody help me in doing this? Thanks

Comment: could you please explain the sorting for `user==1` in your expected output?

Comment: Apologies for the wrong output... Now have changed it

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
In [274]: df['rank'] = df.sort_values(['user','date']) \
                         .groupby(['user'])['date'] \
                         .rank(method='min').astype(int)


In [277]: df.sort_values(['user','date'])
Out[277]:
   user       date  rank
1     1 2015-01-11     1
2     1 2015-01-11     1
3     1 2015-05-08     3
4     1 2015-07-08     4
0     1 2016-03-18     5
6     2 2015-02-10     1
7     2 2015-09-08     2
8     2 2016-01-01     3
9     2 2016-01-01     3
5     2 2016-03-17     5
```