# Polars - How to sort dates and assigning a rank for UniqueID - Python

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars, rust-polars

Relatively new to Polars. I am trying to GroupBy a UniqueID in a Dataframe, and rank based on a datetime column, with the oldest date being ranked as 1 etc...

I saw the code in Pandas but rank() has not been applied as an expression just yet in Polars. Any tips as how to do this ?

```
In [274]: df['rank'] = df.sort_values(['user','date']) \
                         .groupby(['user'])['date'] \
                         .rank(method='min').astype(int)


In [277]: df.sort_values(['user','date'])
Out[277]:
   user       date  rank
1     1 2015-01-11     1
2     1 2015-01-11     1
3     1 2015-05-08     3
4     1 2015-07-08     4
0     1 2016-03-18     5
6     2 2015-02-10     1
7     2 2015-09-08     2
8     2 2016-01-01     3
9     2 2016-01-01     3
5     2 2016-03-17     5
```

[Sorting the dates and assigning a rank - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096311/sorting-the-dates-and-assigning-a-rank-python)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

So polars has already a rank function implemented. So the problem becomes pretty straight forward. :)

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "user": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "date": [
            date(2015, 1, 11),
            date(2015, 1, 11),
            date(2015, 5, 8),
            date(2015, 7, 8),
            date(2016, 3, 18),
            date(2015, 2, 10),
            date(2015, 9, 8),
            date(2016, 1, 1),
            date(2016, 1, 1),
            date(2016, 3, 17),
        ],
    }
)

df = df.with_column(pl.col("date").
               rank(method="min").
               over(["user"]).alias("rank"))




>>> df
shape: (10, 3)
┌──────┬────────────┬──────┐
│ user ┆ date       ┆ rank │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ date       ┆ u32  │
╞══════╪════════════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2015-01-11 ┆ 1    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 2015-01-11 ┆ 1    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 2015-05-08 ┆ 3    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 2015-07-08 ┆ 4    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...  ┆ ...        ┆ ...  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 2015-09-08 ┆ 2    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 2016-01-01 ┆ 3    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 2016-01-01 ┆ 3    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 2016-03-17 ┆ 5    │
└──────┴────────────┴──────┘
```